# How to download a file to the scoped storage of Android App running a Trusted Web Activity that displays my Progressive Web App?

Tags: android-intent, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity, custom-url-protocol

I am working on an Android app that displays a Progressive Web App (PWA) through a Trusted Web Activity (TWA). The app uses scoped storage for security purposes.

I need to provide a way for the user to download a file on clicking a button from the PWA and save it to the app's scoped storage. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to do this.

I went through some SO answers which says postMessage() is disabled on trusted web activity so related answers goes out of the picture.

I tried to override the onNewIntent() method of the Android Browser Helper library's LauncherActivity class and registered an intent filter to intercept custom URL schemes that I can trigger from the web app (PWA). However, the application closes upon launching the said intent URL.

Need to find a solution for this. Any help is appreciated.